# radio button checked javascript - no jquery

Tags: javascript, radio-button

below function seems to be not working..

```
function myCalculator () {

    var operator = document.getElementsByName("operator");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var firstDig = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstDig").value);
    var secondDig = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondDig").value);   

    for (var i=0; i<operator.length; i++){

        var currentOperator = operator[i].id;

        if(currentOperator.checked == "Add"){
            var add = firstDig + secondDig;
                output = add;
        };


    };

        }
```

somehow the "if" parameter is returning false but, i got the element with the property checked...im making a simple calculator...below is the html...

```
<fieldset>

    <label>Enter Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstDig" />
    <input type="text" id="secondDig" />
        <br/> <br/>
    <label>Select Operator:</label>
    <br/><br />

    <input type="radio" id="Add" name="operator" checked="checked" />
        <label for = "Add">Add</label>

    <input type="radio" id="Subt" name="operator" />
        <label for = "Subt">Subtract</label>

    <input type="radio" id="Divi" name="operator" />
        <label for = "Divi">Divide</label>

    <input type="radio" id="Multi" name="operator" />
        <label for = "Multi">Multiply</label>

</fieldset>


<fieldset>
    <p>RESULT</p>
    <input type="text" id="output" />
    <button type="button" onclick="myCalculator()">Calculate</button>
</fieldset>
```

im still learning the foundations of javascript so im not that inetrested in jquery at the moment...all answers are appreciated...thanks

Answer (score 3):

`checked` property will have the value true/false, so you need to get the checked radio and then see whether its id is `Add`(You don't have value assigned to the radio elements instead they have id).

In the same way `output` is a input element, so you need to assign its value

```
function myCalculator() {

    var operator = document.getElementsByName("operator");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var firstDig = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstDig").value);
    var secondDig = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondDig").value);

    for (var i = 0; i < operator.length; i++) {

        var currentOperator = operator[i],
            result = '';

        if (currentOperator.checked) {
            if (currentOperator.id == "Add") {
                result = firstDig + secondDig;
            } else if (currentOperator.id == "Subt") {
                result = firstDig - secondDig;
            }
            output.value = result;
        };


    };

}
```

Comment: `currentOperator ` itself is holding the `id` so it shud be `currentOperator== "Add"`

Comment: okay, so i have extended my if statement with an else if and it stopped working...i thought i had it

Comment: @UniWorld http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k96w03nm/2/ - you one if condition to see whether it is checked if so then check the id as shown in the fiddle

Comment: @Arun P Johny - thanks...i just realised that logically structuring codes is the key...this is kinda hard for begginers like me...

Answer (score 1):

```
if(currentOperator.checked == "Add"){..
```

is wrong. It can only have 2 values `true` or `false`. you can check it like:

```
if(currentOperator == "Add" && operator[i].checked){..
```

Also `output = add;`

shud be

```
 output.value = add;
```

Answer (score 0):

change
output = add;
to
output.value = add;

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<operand.length; i++){
var currentOperand = operand[i];
if (currentOperand.checked && currentOperand.id == "Add") {
var add = firstDig + secondDig;
output.value = add;
}else if (currentOperand,checked && currentOperand.id == "Subt"){
var subt = firstDig - secondDig;
output.value = subt;
};
```

i have extended my if statement with an else if and it stopped working...thought i had it